# Web HUE is not getting loaded though HUE is workin on the port 8000

Tags: apache, hue

I have installed the Hue on the Linux whixh is an instance from Azure. I have made all the required changes in ambari and hue.ini conf file. And when I run the supervisor job, it runs fine
COMMAND   PID    USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
hue     83933 sshuser    3u  IPv4 15707246      0t0  TCP *:8000 (LISTEN)

But when I try to access the wb hue, I don't get any page loaded. It shows refused to connect.

Tried deleting caches and reset up was done.
I am using hue 4.7 version and I don't find any issues in error.log file. Yet, I don't see any data in access.log file. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have

> http_host=0.0.0.0

in the hue.ini?

Comment: Yes , I did and it just worked today. But could you please help me setting hiveserver2 with hue? I have seen many posts opened and I couldn't find any answer.  I am getting the " tsocket reads 0 bytes". I don't have thrift server, I am using beeline hive2 . When I try to connect beeline thru jdbc it worked fine, but I couldn't integrate hue with hive. Please help me out in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

@Ruthikajawar here is a working hue.ini for ambari

https://github.com/steven-dfheinz/HDP3-Hue-Service/blob/Hue.4.6.0/configuration/live.hue.ini

I have noticed that sometimes, after initial install, it takes 1 or 2 restarts to get the WEBUI to work.  I have also noticed sometimes, after a restart, it takes quite a few moments before the WEBUI starts to respond.

Give it some time after restart and check the WEBUI.  If you still are not getting it to answer you need to check /var/log/hue/error.log as it should be very specific with errors causing the WEBUI to fail on startup.

Comment: Thanks Steven. This works now. But could you please help me in the configuration of dashboard for data visualisation. I was able to set up data and i can see widgets and all but i am not able to acces them. can you please guide...

Comment: which dashboard are you referring to?   If you need more help with HUE, create a new post. Also, check out https://discourse.gethue.com